# Reset text and go to the specific frame as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to reset the text whenever I have pressed a button and after that it will go to the specific frame where I already labeled it. However, the text won't reset even though I put the reset text before gotoAndStop();

How can I solve this?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
payment_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPayment);

function onClickPayment(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (myText1.text == "")
    {
        trace('Cannot proceed! There is no items in your shopping bag.');
    }

    else
    {
        myText1.text = "";

        gotoAndStop("purchased");
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Your answer much appreciated!

Comment: How do you know that it hasn't been reset? When you change frame you can't see `myText1` anymore.

Comment: @puggsoy: when I change frame and I go back before frame purchased, the text still there sir

Comment: Strange. Try setting `myText1.text = ""` at the start of the frame's code instead, so that it gets reset when you switch to that frame.

Comment: Note that gotoAndStop() does not happen immediately. First the code will return from onClickPayment and proceed from the calling point till the end of frame, any code that is not guarded by conditions will be executed, only then gotoAndStop will happen.

Comment: Can you provide a FLA file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are changing the frame of the MovieClip containing the textfield.  If so, then if the new frame and the current frame have different keyframes that contain the textfield, the text in the textfield will be set back to the default, regardless of whatever changes you make to it in this code, when you return to the first frame.